# How to analyze the Scalar DL's contract performance?

Tags: scalardl

I want to measure Scalar DL's contract performance.
I have two questions the following below.

1. Goal of response time
   I would like to compare the standard benchmark results of Scalar DL.
   I want to know the target response time of Scalar DL design?
2. How to analyze benchmark results?
   Generally, response time analysis of benchmark is used by average, median, 90% percentile.
   Does Scalar DL's contract benchmark need other metrics and analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The performance(latency) of Scalar DL depends on your contract. For example, a contract that handles 10 assets is 5 times slower than another contract that handles 2 assets. It's a rough estimation because Scalar DL reads and writes other records on the storage.
2. Checking the throughput(Contracts per second) and the latency (average, 50/90/99 percentile, and the maximum are useful)
   And also, the CPU usage and IOPS of disks of each Cassandra node will help you analyze the bottleneck.